# Sharepoint Column Formatting - Basic

Tags: json, sharepoint, formatting, sharepoint-online

I have a very basic sharepoint list with 3 columns as below:

Date1        |   Date2       |   CalculatedDateDif (gets months between two dates 
)
01/01/2018   | 01/03/2018    | 2 
01/01/2018   | 01/04/2018    | 3

I am formatting the CalculatedDateDif column to show error icon when value less than or equal to 2 using the default [microsoft JSON code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)! below:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "debugMode": true,
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField <= 2,'sp-field-severity--warning', '')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(@currentField <= 2,'Error', '')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

For some strange reason, It formats all the rows under the calculated column and removes the value from the calculated column.

I've tried to replace @currentField with @CalculatedDateDif, and no luck.

I am using Sharepoint online.

Answer (score 0):

Go to list settings, and edit the **CalculatedDateDif** column, select **The data type returned from this formula is**: **Single line of text**, and then save it.

[image]

[image]